# Count minimum values in a vector, where the minumum values are in consecutive order

Tags: r, count, min

As the title says, and it's probably very easy, but how can I count the number of minimum values in a vector, or more specific in a subset of vector:

Down below is an example:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
```

so i want the output to be equal to 3 (since there are three 1's)

Comment: `table(sort(a))[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `==` to get a logical vector, `sum()` then counts number of `TRUE` in a logical vector.

```
sum(a == min(a))
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer everyone, it works well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table`, i.e.

```
table(a)[1]
#1 
#3
```

or If you want to unname it,

```
unname(table(a)[1])
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tabulate`

```
tabulate(a)[1]
#[1] 3
```